JavaScript popup calling different images onclick
I have created an image popup which uses javaScript to call different images onClick.
HTML Code snippet for the same as below.
<img onmouseover="imgload();" src="11.jpg">
<img onmouseover="imgbarb();" src="13.jpg">

I use the below javaScript to load the onmouseover function
JavaScript code for 11.jpg
function imgload() {
  var imgContainers   = document.querySelectorAll('.img-container');
  var tooltipElements = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip');
  var popup           = document.getElementById('imagePopup1');
  var popupOverlay    = document.getElementById('imagePopupOverlay1');
  var popupImage      = document.getElementById('popupImage1');
  var closePopupBtn   = document.getElementById('closeImagePopupBtn1');
  // Show tooltip on hover
  imgContainers.forEach((container, index) => {
    var tooltip = container.querySelector('.tooltip');
    var image   = container.querySelector('img');
    container.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
      tooltip.style.display = 'block';
    });
    container.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
      tooltip.style.display = 'none';
    });
    // Open full-size image popup when image is clicked
    image.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var imageSrc               = "11-new.jpg";
      popupImage.src             = imageSrc;
      popup.style.display        = 'block';
      popupOverlay.style.display = 'block';
    });
  });
  // Close the image popup when clicking the close button
  closePopupBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    popup.style.display        = 'none';
    popupOverlay.style.display = 'none';
  });
  // Close the image popup when clicking the overlay
  popupOverlay.addEventListener('click', function() {
    popup.style.display        = 'none';
    popupOverlay.style.display = 'none';
  });
}

JavaScript code for 13.jpg
function imgbarb() {
  var imgContainers   = document.querySelectorAll('.img-container');
  var tooltipElements = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip');
  var popup           = document.getElementById('imagePopup1');
  var popupOverlay    = document.getElementById('imagePopupOverlay1');
  var popupImage      = document.getElementById('popupImage1');
  var closePopupBtn   = document.getElementById('closeImagePopupBtn1');
  // Show tooltip on hover
  imgContainers.forEach((container, index) => {
    var tooltip = container.querySelector('.tooltip');
    var image   = container.querySelector('img');
    container.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
      tooltip.style.display = 'block';
    });
    container.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
      tooltip.style.display = 'none';
    });
    // Open full-size image popup when image is clicked
    image.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var imageSrc               = "13-new.jpg";
      popupImage.src             = imageSrc;
      popup.style.display        = 'block';
      popupOverlay.style.display = 'block';
    });
  });
  // Close the image popup when clicking the close button
  closePopupBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    popup.style.display        = 'none';
    popupOverlay.style.display = 'none';
  });
  // Close the image popup when clicking the overlay
  popupOverlay.addEventListener('click', function() {
    popup.style.display        = 'none';
    popupOverlay.style.display = 'none';
  });
}

I have around 30+ images. So each time when I wish to create a popup image for a new image, I have to create a new function and then call onmouseover everytime.
I feel it is very cumbersome to manage as it also increases the code.
Is there a simple way to this so I do not have to create a new function every time when I add a new image for popup?
I tried if and else, arrays and other stuff, but it did not work.

So basically the only difference between your functions for all the  is the imageSrc? Then you can use data-attributes to set it for  elements and use it instead of hardcoded js values. This should allow you to have 1 function attached to all the images you want. Also im not sure you really need to attach that many event listeners for closePopupBtn and popupOverlay, isnt it enough to attach them only once?

@SergeySosunov - Could you please share an example to what you are referring to?

I would appreciate a reason for the downvote.

why don't you use a classic addEventListener, and also a mousetnter event; because every move inside the same img will call repeatedly the same function...

@MisterJojo - Could you please illustrate what you are referring to?

Could you add more information about your interface element and cinematic involved here ?

Answer is based on folowing assumptions:

The only difference of the onmouseover functions for all the image is the var imageSrc
Elements the code means to affect ('.img-container') are not added dynamically

The issues:

Hardcoded imgSrc inside js function - fixed with data attributes
Using onmouseover means that the functions will be called again and again on every onmouseover event for those images, which will cause tens/hundreds/thousands/... functions executions, and each execution will add more EventListeners - fixed with DOMContentLoaded

Html part:
<img data-popup-src="11-new.jpg" src="11.jpg" />
<img data-popup-src="13-new.jpg" src="13.jpg" />

JS part:
function setupImagePopups() {
  var imgContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.img-container');
  var popup = document.getElementById('imagePopup1');
  var popupOverlay = document.getElementById('imagePopupOverlay1');
  var popupImage = document.getElementById('popupImage1');
  var closePopupBtn = document.getElementById('closeImagePopupBtn1');

  // Attach events to all containers dynamically
  imgContainers.forEach(container => {
    var tooltip = container.querySelector('.tooltip');
    var image = container.querySelector('img');

    // Show tooltip on hover
    container.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
      tooltip.style.display = 'block';
    });

    container.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
      tooltip.style.display = 'none';
    });

    // Open full-size image popup on click
    image.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var imageSrc = image.getAttribute('data-popup-src'); // DIFFERENCE
      popupImage.src = imageSrc;
      popup.style.display = 'block';
      popupOverlay.style.display = 'block';
    });
  });

  // Close popup on button click or overlay click
  closePopupBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    popup.style.display = 'none';
    popupOverlay.style.display = 'none';
  });

  popupOverlay.addEventListener('click', function() {
    popup.style.display = 'none';
    popupOverlay.style.display = 'none';
  });
}

// Call setupImagePopups on DOMContentLoaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  setupImagePopups();
});


Spectacular. This is exactly how I wanted. Thank you very much. +1 and answer accepted :)
